# Convert List of Associations into Association of Lists

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, neural-networks

For neural networks mathematica likes 2 ways to structure training sets:

```
listFormatData = {
<|"Input" -> input1, "OutputKey1" -> OutputKey1Input1Output, ...|>,
<|"Input" -> input2, "OutputKey1" -> OutputKey1Input2Output, ...|>,
...
}
```

and

```
assocFormatData = <|
"Input" -> {input1, input2, ...}, 
"OutputKey1" -> {OutputKey1Input1Output, OutputKey1Input2Output, ...}
, ...
|>
```

Is the a stock way to convert these 2 formats properly?

Concrete examples:

```
listData = {
<|"Input" -> 1, "double" -> 2, "squared" -> 1|>,
<|"Input" -> 2, "double" -> 4, "squared" -> 4|>,
<|"Input" -> 3, "double" -> 6, "squared" -> 9|>
}
```

and

```
assocData = <|
"Input" -> {1, 2, 3}, 
"double" -> {2, 4, 6}, 
"squared" -> {1, 4, 9}
|>
```

Comment: What does `Normal[Transpose[Dataset[listData]]]` return for you? (Also if you replace `listData` with `assocData`?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `AllowedHeads` option of [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose) to do this:

```
tr = Transpose[listData, AllowedHeads -> {Association, List}]
```

> <|"Input" -> {1, 2, 3}, "double" -> {2, 4, 6}, "squared" -> {1, 4, 9}|>

and back:

```
Transpose[tr, AllowedHeads -> {Association, List}]
```

> {<|"Input" -> 1, "double" -> 2, "squared" -> 1|>, <|"Input" -> 2, 
>     "double" -> 4, "squared" -> 4|>, <|"Input" -> 3, "double" -> 6, 
>     "squared" -> 9|>}

Answer (score 12):

```
Merge[listData, Identity]
```

> <|"Input" -> {1, 2, 3}, "double" -> {2, 4, 6}, "squared" -> {1, 4, 9}|>

```
listFormatData = {<|"Input" -> input1,  "OutputKey1" -> OutputKey1Input1Output|>,
   <|"Input" -> input2, "OutputKey1" -> OutputKey1Input2Output|>};
Merge[listFormatData , Identity]
```

> <|"Input" -> {input1, input2}, 
>         "OutputKey1" -> {OutputKey1Input1Output, OutputKey1Input2Output}|>

Answer (score 12):

A function that is of great use here, is `AssociationTranspose` in the `GeneralUtilities` package. It does the same thing as regular transpose, but works with `List` and `Associations` alike (and mixtures of the two):

```
listData = {
  <|"Input" -> 1, "double" -> 2, "squared" -> 1|>, 
  <|"Input" -> 2, "double" -> 4, "squared" -> 4|>,
  <|"Input" -> 3, "double" -> 6, "squared" -> 9|>
};
assocData = <|"Input" -> {1, 2, 3}, "double" -> {2, 4, 6}, "squared" -> {1, 4, 9}|>;
GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose[listData]  === assocData
GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose[assocData] === listData
```

> > Out[11]= True
> >
> > Out[12]= True

Answer (score 1):

```
Query[Transpose] @ listData
```

<|"Input" -> {1, 2, 3}, "double" -> {2, 4, 6}, "squared" -> {1, 4, 9}|

> 

Transpose back:

```
Query[Transpose] @ Query[Transpose] @ listData == listData
```

True